# Sequelize: Use multiple keys from source to include target model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a like model that stores the id of the liked item, the user.id, business.id and the type of item it is as a STRING.

```
const Like = sequelize.define('like', {
businessId : {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
itemId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
userId: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
type: {type: DataTypes.STRING}})
```

An item can be a Sedan, Truck, or Van. All have their own models.

I'd like to query all the likes from the user and separate them into their respected models included into the query

I have my like model association like this:

```
Like.associate = function(models) {
  Like.hasOne(models.sedan, {sourceKey: 'itemId', foreignKey: 'id'})};
```

This lets me include my sedan model and connects them by the like "itemId" and the "sedan.id".

The problem is that in an postgres db the ids start at 1 and just increment, so a sedan.id and a truck.id can both have an id = 5 which I store in the like itemId as well as the type of item in the type key.

ex:

```
businessId : 23,
itemId: 5, // This id belongs to the item which can come from 'sedan','truck','van'
userId: 12,
type: 'Sedan' // This section lets you know where the id came from
```

What I ultimately want to do is get all the user likes and include the other models with their respected like.

How my query looks.

```
Like.findAll({
    where: {userId: userId},
    include: [
        {
            model: Sedan,
            required: false
        },
        {
            model: Truck,
            required: false
        },
        {
            model: Van,
            required: false
        }
    ]
})
```

This won't work because an id from a truck can also call an id from a sedan. I can't add the type to the "where"

```
where: {userId: userId, type: 'Sedan'}
```

because it'll effect the rest of the included models and I can't seem to find how to add the like type to each included model as a filter

I've also tried to add it to the association part of the like model but can't seem to find a way to add the type.
Hoping there was something like a "sourceScope".
ex:

```
Like.hasOne(models.product, {sourceKey: 'itemId', foreignKey: 'id', sourceScope: {type: 'Sedan'})
```

but I can't seem to find a way to tie in the item type.

Is there a way to do this or a better approach to the whole thing?
My goal is to store all the likes in one table as to make the like system dynamic and I want to be able to include the item with each like based on different combinations of like model keys
GOAL: 
Get all likes from a user and include each item to the like object, based on the user.id, like.itemId and like.type

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional array destructuring to do this.

```
Like.findAll({
    where: {userId: userId},
    include: [
        ...(type === 'Sedan' && [{ model: Sedan, required: true }]),
        ...(type === 'Truck' && [{ model: Sedan, required: true }]),
        ...(type === 'Van' && [{ model: Sedan, required: true }])
    ]
})
```

If the `type === 'Sedan'` it will destructure the array and return the object `{ model: Sedan, required: true }` to your "include" array.

---

Alternatively you could setup your likes as a linking table:

```
User = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John',
  ...
}]

Vehicle = [{
  id: 1,
  type: 'Sedan',
  ...
}]

Likes = [{
  userId: 1,
  vehicleId: 1,
  likedAt: '2020-01-30'
}]
```

Comment: Where are you getting type from, when I do it this way I get "type is not defined"

Comment: Just define type outside the `.findAll`. Ie. const type = 'Sedan'

Comment: The type comes from the findAll, the type is part of the like model, each type is different with each like that comes back